# How to destroy paperJS Scope

Tags: vue.js, paperjs

I am trying to destory the paperJS scope but the diagram is still visible.

I used the following.

```
this.paperScopes[i].remove(); 
this.paperScopes[i].clear();
this.paperScopes[i] = null;
```

Where I am keeping multiple scopes in an array with paperScope. 
I have used VueJS to show multiple canvases and what happens is that each time the application dom is updated the canvas size grows.

Comment: `scope.remove(); scope = null;` should be enough. Can you try to reproduce the problem in a fiddle so that we can help you better ?

Comment: Thanks for the response and help :) . Sasensi. 
What finally worked for me is. 

    this.paperScopes[i].project.remove(); 
    this.paperScopes[i].remove(); 
    this.paperScopes[i].clear(); 
    this.paperScopes[i] = null; 
    this.allCanvas[i] = null; 

I had to remove the project. If I do not do so the previous diagram remains and their is a zooming problem. I wrote the code in a project So I would have to create a small demo on jsFiddle of the strange behaviour of canvas size expanding. But it has stopped after writing. 

    this.paperScopes[i].project.remove();